# Automated removal of unused QML imports

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm working with a pretty large Qt/QML code base, and I am looking for way to detect and remove all unused QML imports. How can this be done? Is there some way to automate it?

I believe that removing unused QML imports is a good way to keep the codebase clean. Also, according [the QML Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/Furkanzmc/QML-Coding-Guide#import-statements), it will improve loading performance:

> Imports take time in QML. And If you are developing for a device with low system specifications, then you will want to optimize as much as possible. In that case, try to minimize the number of imports you use in your QML file.

Answer (score 1):

After almost two years, I've found a conventional way to do it, provided by Qt via their tool *qmlLint* :

> You may now disable warnings on a per category basis, for example by
> default qmllint will inform you about unused imports:
>
> ```
> import QtQuick
> import QtQuick3D // Info: DEM.qml:2:1: Unused
> import at DEM.qml:2:1
>
> Text {
>     id: textElement
>     text: "Hello world!"
>     anchors.centerIn: parent
> }
> ```
>
> If you wish, you can now either suppress this information by passing
> --unused-imports disable. Or you can turn this informational message into a full blown warning by using --unused-imports warning. In that
> case, as with all warnings, the unused import warning will make
> qmllint return an exit code of 1 ; that will cause failure in any CI
> or pre-commit hooks that use the tool. See the output of qmllint
> --help for the complete list of warning categories.

Source : https://www.qt.io/blog/whats-new-in-qml-tooling-in-qt-6.2

Answer (score 0):

You could parse every single QML file and search for QML dependencies in the code, then remove every other dependency copied by `winqtqmldeploy`.